# Laravel how to output db records as XML?

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I cant deal with such simple (I think) thing like output records from database as XML. I have eloquent model named Customer and I want to send to output all customers from db so I've tried to install response macro (http://www.laravel-tricks.com/tricks/responsexml-macro) and I call it like this:

```
public function showCustomers()
{
   $customers = Customer::all()->toArray();
   return Response::xml($customers);
}
```

but then I got error:

> "SimpleXMLElement::addChild(): unterminated entity reference M"

I tried also other solution which used `SimpleXMLELement` also so the result was the same.

Comment: Read the comments on [laravel-tricks](http://www.laravel-tricks.com/tricks/responsexml-macro#comment-1453496585). There's a modified version that supports numeric arrays (which you need)

Comment: Almost complete solution. I've also changed a little code that is described there : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17028414/2487793

Comment: I suggest you answer your own question and document what you did for future visitors of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this package:

https://github.com/mtownsend5512/response-xml

Then it's as easy as

```
$customers = Customer::all();
return response()->xml($customers);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dwightwatson/sitemap - very useful utility, works with **Laravel 4.*, 5.***.

Install:

`composer require watson/sitemap`

Add the service provider to your config/app.php file.

```
Watson\Sitemap\SitemapServiceProvider::class
```

Add the alias to the facade, also in config/app.php.

```
'Sitemap' => Watson\Sitemap\Facades\Sitemap::class
```

Usage example:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Categories;
use App\Models\Essays;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Watson\Sitemap\Sitemap;

/**
 * Class SitemapController, generates and shows xml sitemap
 *
 * @package App\Http\Controllers
 */
class SitemapController
{
    public function index() {
        // init sitemap obj
        $sitemap = new Sitemap(
            Cache::store('file'),
            new Request()
        );

        $essayModel = new Essays();
        $categoryModel = new Categories();

        $categoriesArr = $categoryModel->getAllPublishedCategories();

        // add to sitemap all the categories
        foreach ($categoriesArr as $categoryRes) {
            $sitemap->addTag(
                url(
                    "/" . config('custom.urlBases.essaysCategory')
                    . "/" . Str::slug($categoryRes->name, "-") . "-{$categoryRes->id}"
                ),
                $categoryRes->cat_publication_time,
                'daily',
                '0.5'
            );
        }

        $essaysArr = $essayModel->getAllEssays();

        // add to sitemap all the essays
        foreach ($essaysArr as $essay) {
            $sitemap->addTag(
                url(config('custom.urlBases.essayPage') . '/' . $essay->url . '-' . $essay->id),
                $essay->publication_time,
                'daily',
                '0.5'
            );
        }

        return $sitemap->render();
    }
}
```

Returns content like next:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
    <loc>page-url-here</loc>
    <lastmod>2017-02-08T19:52:37+00:00</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
```

Answer (score 0):

$customers = Customer::all();
return response()->xml($customers);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
// macros.php
Response::macro('xml', function(array $vars, $status = 200, array $header = [], $xml = null)
{
    if (is_null($xml)) {
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response/>');
    }
    foreach ($vars as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            Response::xml($value, $status, $header, $xml->addChild($key));
        } else {
            $xml->addChild($key, $value);
        }
    }
    if (empty($header)) {
        $header['Content-Type'] = 'application/xml';
    }
    return Response::make($xml->asXML(), $status, $header);
});
?>

<?php
// app/start/global.php
// add require macros.php
require app_path() . '/macros.php';
?>

<?php
// How to use
// routes.php
Route::get('api.{ext}', function()
{
    $data = ['status' => 'OK'];
    $ext = File::extension(Request::url());
    return Response::$ext($data);
})->where('ext', 'xml|json');
```